# How to rename a table in a database which have referential integrity maintain?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

After giving the below command

```
set integrity for table_name off
```

I am getting following error

> DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -290, SQLSTATE: 55039, SQLERRMC: null Message:
>   Table space access

What could be the possible reason for this?

What I want to achieve is: I want to temporarily disable the constraints so that I can rename the actual table and create a new table with the actual table name. Then i will enable the constraints. Any help of pointers in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you thoght about a cheaper method like using an alias (or view)?

Answer (score 0):

`set integrity` does not "disable constraints".

As per the [SET INTEGRITY statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000998.html) manual page, `set integrity off`

> Specifies that the tables are placed in set integrity pending state. Only very limited activity is allowed on a table that is in set integrity pending state.

WHen you try to rename a table with constraints you get SQL0750N, which says:

> If the error pertains to a RENAME statement, drop the view, materialized query
>   table, trigger, SQL function, SQL method, check constraint, referential constraint,
>   expression-based index, or XSR object dependent on the table before issuing the 
>   RENAME statement. Objects dependent on the table can be determined by querying the 
>   catalog.

I.e. you have to drop the constraint, rename the table, then add the constraint back. It is just the way it works. Something like `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` will do the drop and re-create of constraints required, but then that until actually physically moves the table data, so is maybe not a good idea if you simply want to do a rename. Many GUI tolls (such as IBM Data Studio) will generate the required DROP, RENAME, CREATE statements for you.

The error you currently have `SQL0290N  Table space access is not allowed` is a different issue, and will be due to some other cause.